# How can I use jQuery UI (jqueryui) with StackBlitz and TypeScript and NPM

Tags: jquery, typescript, jquery-ui, commonjs, stackblitz

I am trying to use jQuery UI in [StackBlitz](http://www.stackblitz.com).

I am also trying to install it as a dependency and without a script tag.

I understand that I have to add @types/jquery and @types/jqueryui as dependencies.

But when I add this in the index.ts

```
import $ from "jquery";
import "jqueryui";
```

I get the error: "jQuery is not defined"

Comment: I'm a bit confused,  did you manage to write the question,  search and test a solution and post the answer in the same minute?

Comment: I researched the issue and found related answers. I pieced together the solution for my particular case and thought someone else might appreciate the combined, specific solution. Judging from the prominent "Answer your own question" option on every question I assumed this was welcome around here. Guess I was wrong...

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, asking and answering a question that doesn't exist on the site yet is a perfectly valid use case and helps other people who stumble across it in the future (like me) - thanks Ray!

Answer (score 2):

This code seems to do the trick:

```
import $ from "jquery";
declare var global: any
global.jQuery = $;
import "jqueryui";
```

Here is a screenshot of the dependencies:

[image]

Comment: Thanks I'm able to use it like this. How about css? I can't see jquery CSS though.